# What does ま、いっか。めんどくさいし mean?

Tags: translation

I have trouble with interpreting the following sentence:

> ま、いっか。めんどくさいし

It has to do with something being troublesome.

Comment: The 「ま」 at the beginning is important, too.

Comment: So how do you interpret it improperly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「ま...いっか」

is how we colloquially pronounce:

> 「まあいいか」,

which means kind of like "***Meh!***"

You are telling yourself not to worry or to be concerned about what is happening now or has just happened.

The 「いい」 part means "good", and you are indeed **calling it good** as-is.

The whole sentence means:

> "Meh! This is too tiresome!"

Answer (score 1):

“ま、いっか。めんどくさい(面倒臭い)し”, I would interpret it;

Well, it isn’t so bad, and it’s troublesome (to do it) , or

Well, let’s leave it (as it is), It’s tiresome (to redo it).